# ¿Como cambiar el color a boton con Jquery o JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo 5 botones en la parte superior de mi vida, el tema es que cuando selecciono 1 boton este quede activado por decirlo o con la clase `iq-bg-primary` pero si presiono el boton 2 el primer boton vuelva a su color base `iq-bg-success` y el otro cambie, trate con un change pero no funciono nada, mientras esoty con el click y me funciona pero me deja todos los que marque seleccionado.

HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-8 text-right">
                    @php
                    \App\Status::pluck('name','id')->map(function ($name,$id){
                    echo
                    '<button type="submit" class="btn mb-3 btn iq-bg-success rounded-pill text-right" name="type"
                        id="'.$name.'" value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</button>';
                    })
                    @endphp
                </div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').on('click',function(){
            console.log($(this).val());
            $(this).removeClass("iq-bg-success"); 
            $(this).addClass("iq-bg-primary");
     });
});
```

No se como podría validar que si selecciono al boton 2 el primero se deshabilite.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes lograrlo quitando primero la clase a todos los botones asi:

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('button').on('click',function(){
                console.log($(this).val());
                $(".iq-bg-primary").removeClass("iq-bg-primary"); 
                $(this).addClass("iq-bg-primary");
         });
    });
```

```css
.iq-bg-success {
  background-color: green;
}
.iq-bg-primary {
  background-color: blue;
{
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" class="btn mb-3 btn iq-bg-success rounded-pill text-right" name="type"
                        id="'.$name.'" value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn mb-3 btn iq-bg-success rounded-pill text-right" name="type"
                        id="'.$name.'" value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn mb-3 btn iq-bg-success rounded-pill text-right" name="type"
                        id="'.$name.'" value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn mb-3 btn iq-bg-success rounded-pill text-right" name="type"
                        id="'.$name.'" value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn mb-3 btn iq-bg-success rounded-pill text-right" name="type"
                        id="'.$name.'" value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</button>
```

Comment: Esta interesante eso, pero si presiono sin qerer otro boton me quedan 2 botones activados y solo quiero que siempre quede 1 seleccionado y que si selecciono otro boton se dehabilite el anterior y se agregue la clase al nuevo

Comment: Funciona bien aqui o no?

Comment: A era eso habia tecleado mal como llamar a la clase, vale gracias :D